# Python - Scraping a PDF file from a URL

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I want to scrape pdf files from this site
https://www.sigmaths.net/Reader.php?var=manuels/ph/physique_pilote_7b.pdf
I tried this code for that but it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me why, please?

```
res = requests.get('https://www.sigmaths.net/Reader.php?var=manuels/ph/physique_7b.pdf')
with open('C:\\Users\\sioud\\Desktop\\Manuels scolaires TN\\1\\test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
f.write(ress.content)
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What does this code do?  What do you expect it to do?  What output/errors do you see?  Is your code properly formatted when you're trying to run it (is `f.write()` correctly indented in the `with` block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = requests.get('https://www.sigmaths.net/manuels/ph/physique_7b.pdf',stream=True)
with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

your url is pointing to a reader `https://www.sigmaths.net/Reader.php?var=manuels/ph/physique_7b.pdf`, `remove the 'reader.php?var=` for the actual pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).
Check out my solution code.

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
pdfurl = u"https://www.sigmaths.net/manuels/ph/physique_7b.pdf";
urlretrieve(pdfurl, "test.pdf")
```

And you will find the required pdf download under the name `test.pdf`